# How do I draw two circles whose edges meet?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In a `<canvas>` element, I'm animating a collection of circles that can collide with one another. Occasionally these collisions occur between iterations of the main loop, and on the next iteration the loops are "inside" each other.

To combat this, I've calculated the point of impact (C) between the two circles, and now wish to nudge the circles' coordinates so that their edges meet on this point of impact. I've been playing around with inverting their velocities to move them away from each other along their original vectors, but I can't seem to get it right.

How do I calculate the "nudged" coordinates of A and B so their edges meet at C?

[image: Diagram of collision]

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle with your existing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/VtM7F/

[image]

Here's how:

```
var dx=C.x-A.x;
var dy=C.y-A.y;
var angleC=Math.atan2(dy,dx);

var newAX=C.x+A.radius*Math.cos(angleC-PI);
var newAY=C.y+A.radius*Math.sin(angleC-PI);
```

And do the same with B.

Comment: You can simplify it a bit by changing `angleC-PI` -> `angleC` and swap dx and dy diff order, ie. `dx = A.x-C.x`.

Comment: @Epistemex: Yep, thanks for noticing the optimization! My mind went down one path and I forgot to check for shorter paths. :-)  Off-topic: Kudos for your .gif on your profile page!  Do you use any particular encoder?

Comment: Thanks @markE. I tried out a gif.js by JNordberg as it claims differential frame encoding. I had to optimize it from about the resulting ~150kb to 13kb in Photoshop though (but that also involves optimizing the palette). But it was a fun canvas project. :-)